# Getting string not in specific html tag with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
@test <span class="mention">@test</span> @test2 <span class="mention">@test</span>`
```

And I would like to match all words starting with an @ symbol outside the span in Javascript

I have created the RegExp for matching the span objects

```
/<span class="mention"((.*)data-mention="\d+")?>@\w+<\/span>/g
```

But I just can't work out how to get elements not inside the span element!

Comment: Why only a regular expression? HTML is not a regular language, it can't be reliably parsed by individual regular expressions.

Comment: you may perhaps shorten your regex to `/<span[^>].*?<\/span>/g`

Comment: @RobG the library im using only supports regex for these things..

Comment: @MichaelH how about this http://regex101.com/r/dR4bN1/3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a try to extract the desired

**Regex**

```
/(@\w+\b)(?![^>]*?<\/span>)/g
```

**Test String**

```
@test <span class="mention">@test</span> @test2 <span class="mention">@test</span>`
```

**Result**

- MATCH 1

  - 1. [0-5]   `@test`
- MATCH 2

  - 1. [41-47] `@test2`

**Demo**

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/xT4mD6/2)

note that it is not a foolproof solution, it is simply based on your test string.

Comment: Can you help me with one more? Im trying to strip all html tags except those that are <span class="mention">any word</span>, any suggestions?

Comment: you can try `/(<span[^>].*?<\/span>)/g` ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/xT4mD6/5)) to replace every span with text, or `/(<span class="mention".*?\/span>)/g` ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/xT4mD6/6)) if you want to replace only span with the specified class attribute.

Comment: I actually dont want to replace the span if it has a class.. but want to remove all html tags besides that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541441/removing-all-html-tags-except-for-html-with-specific-class-using-regex?noredirect=1#comment39879382_25541441

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regex. It's HTML, so use the DOM manipulation methods:

```
var s = '@test <span class="mention">@test</span> @test2 <span class="mention">@test</span>';

var e = document.createElement("div");
e.innerHTML = s;
var spans = e.getElementsByTagName("span");
while (spans.length > 0) {
    e.removeChild(spans[0]);
}
console.log(e.innerHTML);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mzny7857/

This will leave you with `@test  @test2` which you can then split or match with a regex.