# Removing all html tags except for html with specific class using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this test string

```
@test@test <span class="mention">@test</span> @test2@test <span class="mention">@test</span> test@test.com Test @test.com <br> <a></a> <hr></hr> <span>dsfsfdsdfsdfs asdf </span> <span>test</span> <a>f</a>
```

And I was hoping to remove all tags whilst leaving their content EXCEPT the span with class mention.. In order to be left with the following:

```
@test@test <span class="mention">@test</span> @test2@test <span class="mention">@test</span> test@test.com Test @test.com dsfsfdsdfsdfs asdf test f
```

This is far as I got but it still doesn't work correctly

```
/(?!<span class="mention".*?<\/span>)(<([a-z]*)>(.[^<>]*|)<(\/[a-z]*)>)/g
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2640017

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go

**Regex**

```
/(<span(?![^>]*class="mention")[^>]*>)([^<]*)<\/span>/g
```

**Replace pattern**

```
\2
```

**Test String**

```
@test@test <span class="mention">@test</span> @test2@test <span class="mention">@test</span> test@test.com Test @test.com <br> <a></a> <hr></hr> <span>dsfsfdsdfsdfs asdf </span> <span>test</span> <a>f</a>
```

**Result**

```
@test@test <span class="mention">@test</span> @test2@test <span class="mention">@test</span> test@test.com Test @test.com <br> <a></a> <hr></hr> dsfsfdsdfsdfs asdf  test <a>f</a>
```

**Demo**

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/gF7wW6/2)

this will rip off all the span tags which do not have the specified class attribute `class="mention"`

---

**EDIT**

as requested here is how you can strip off all the html tags except the one which has required mention class

**Regex**

```
/(<(\w+)(?![^>]*class="mention")[^>]*>)([^<]*)<\/\2>|(?:<br>|<br\/>)/g
```

**Replace pattern**

```
\3
```

**Result**

```
@test@test <span class="mention">@test</span> @test2@test <span class="mention">@test</span> test@test.com Test @test.com    dsfsfdsdfsdfs asdf  test f
```

**Demo**

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/gF7wW6/5)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I wasn't exactly the clearest but I wanted to remove all html tags not just spans!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! But I want to keep the actual content and just match the tags

Comment: see http://regex101.com/r/gF7wW6/6 if this is what you are looking for. or perhaps this http://regex101.com/r/gF7wW6/7, removed non capture from br tag too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (?!<span class.*?</span>)(<[^/]*?>).*?(</.*?>)
```

This matches all the things you want.

See Demo.

http://regex101.com/r/uU0hL0/2